# Is it acceptable to pronounce the "T" in "Time" in this specific case?

Tags: pronunciation

My question is that

Does the man pronounce the word "**time**" wrongly in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OR_7h5DaI-E)?

It seems that he doesn't aspirate the "**T**" in "**Time**".

Comment: Maybe. It sounds like he's speaking with an accent, which means he's probably not a native speaker.

Comment: English is quite the language. Native speakers can have *many* different accents from *many* different countries.  Heh. Just consider the many different accents displayed by actors portraying Doctor Who. And that just scratches the surface.

Comment: [The Spanish t is softer or less explosive than the "t" in English.](https://www.thoughtco.com/pronouncing-the-t-3079563)  Regardless of whether your linked speaker is a native Anglophone or not, he's got a strong Spanish / Mexican accent. Obviously not "unacceptable", but you'd hardly want to deliberately imitate him if you're trying to learn "mainstream English".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He *does* pronounce it, just not as harsh as some would pronounce it. In American accents, 'T' is often pronounced as a softer 'D' sound. The accent in this video sounds like a Mexican, or South-American accent.

If the sound was omitted completely then the 'a' and 'i' would either run together, or you'd have a long 'i' sound (as in "ice"), which you don't.

Answer (score 0):

You're right, he doesn't aspirate the T in *time*.

He has a dental stop /t̪/ rather than an alveolar stop /t/. Moreover, he isn't aspirating it (no puff of air).

Voiceless stops in English are supposed to be aspirated at the beginning of a stressed syllable, however, most speakers such as Spanish and Asian English speakers don't often aspirate them.

Therefore *time* should be pronounced [tʰaɪm] but he pronounces it [t̪aɪm] probably because his native language doesn't have aspirated stops.